# Getting error while trying to get CSS selector with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

New to programing in general so may not understand some terms but the question is I am getting errors when I use element = browser.find_element('CSS Code'). I Googled and it states that Selenuim, no longer uses it which I understand and then tried to use element = brower.find_element(By.css_selector after importing from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By but the code still did not work. Also tried element = find_elemnt('CSS Code'). I am trying to get the CSS, even used Xpath as a substitute to see if any would work but non.

Code on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/Dn6234sX

```
from selenium import webdriver brower = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Anyone have any ideas where I am going wrong?

Apologies for the code formatting and not including all of it, still learning how to use this site.

Cheers.

Comment: The error of the code is due to the typo: `brower = ` where it should be `browser =`.

Comment: Agree on that spelling mistake, but the code still works is you continue to use brower. In my case I did make a mistake and lesson learnt. It is something I have to pay attention to while I tend to type fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all of your mistakes are from improper spelling, and or incorrect method names.  I suggest keeping the selenium documentation open and easily able to use it as a reference when writing code. When you fail to get it right the first time, it will save you alot of trouble to simply look up what you got wrong instead of trying over and over again.

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> driver.get('https://automatetheboringstuff.com')
>>> element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/main/div/ul[2]/li[1]/a")
```

[Selenium Documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html)

Comment: Thanks for that tip, just wanted to ask a follow up quesion. Webdriver.common.by import By is just the newer way to doing it right? Modules or code get updated to ensure they continue working? Second, why have you used Xpath and not CSS selector as that is what one is after? Don't know much about Xpath.

Comment: @vee2gee yes importing By is the newer way of doing it.  I used xpath because that is what you first tried in your attempt in the traceback.... If you want to ise css use the By.CSS instead

Comment: I am trying to get it to work but now getting the "driver" not defined error? I have read the documentation for Selenium. https://pastebin.com/uJBcrLgb

Comment: @vee2gee  take a moment and look at the code in my question.  Then take a look at the code in your pastebin.... You should be able to notice that used the variable `browser` instead of `driver`  that is why you are getting the error

Comment: kjdhfgjkdhfkgjdf FUCK!, thanks again. I need to pay more attention to spelling and checking code.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the module documentation helped. https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html and https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-css-selectors. Learning Python from old material that has not been updated is a bit difficult but if you look at the documentation of said modules which I think gets updated regularly wil answer you're questions alongside the community.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33117375)